# Git: переключился на коммит из другой ветки

Tags: git, git-commit, git-branch, branch

Сделал reset из ветки А на коммит из ветки Б, в результате ветка А – клон ветки Б

git reset --hard e562a207b219dc2f82f4166d1568f18e9487d433
git push -f

Можно ли как-то вернуть коммиты из ветки А?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

запускаете `git reflog` и ищите там последний хеш правильного коммита из ветки А. Потом повторяете Вашу команду. Возможно, потом нужно будет почистить за всем.

Comment: Отображается только название ветки и коммит на который был переключен HEAD. Можно ли найти SHA-1 коммита, который был на ветке до reset?

Comment: показывайте скриншот. будем искать

Comment: Дополнительно опишу ситуацию. Есть две ветки А и Б. 
А была смержена в Б
Потом был сделан злополучный reset ветки А на коммит из Б.
Ветка Б при этом не менялась.

Правильно понимаю, что все коммиты ветки А сохранены, но она сейчас привязана к коммиту ветки Б?

Comment: Фух, кажись, разобрался. git reflog помог, спасибо